# How to load a iptable matching module? Or is it required to load it expressly? Some related questions

Tags: kernel, iptables

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I believe the following shows which iptables matching modules are loaded:

```
    sudo cat /proc/net/ip_tables_matches
```

Question: I see conntrack listed three times. Why?

So I tried to see what .so are there which come part of iptables. Listed the .so files under /var/lib/dpkg/info/iptables.list. There are multiple .so there.

All this arose because I wanted to load -m mac module. The following iptables rule was giving an error:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac --mac-source 00-27-0E-33-4B-B2 -j DROP
```

I figured I needed to load mac to have the error go away. How do I load the matching mac-address iptables module? And if I want to load any other iptables match module? Are these not loaded automatically by the kernel on an as needed basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask 4 questions. I can answer 3 of them.

Any required module will be loaded automatically by iptables when it is required. Some years ago, modules had to be specifically loaded. Some critical applications still force load the modules, so that there is no delay when iptables realizes it needs the module.

Now, the issue with your MAC related iptables rule, is bad syntax and not module loaded or not loaded. This line:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac --mac-source 00-27-0E-33-4B-B2 -j DROP
```

Should be this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.88 -m mac --mac-source 00:27:0E:33:4B:B2 -j DROP
```

Your question about conntrack module listed 3 times, I do not know why. Perhaps because you are using it in 3 different ways, but that is just a guess.

Comment: How do you "force load" a module and if you do, where do you get the list of all iptables loadable modules. I would think that the one-time loading would be generally efficient, if memory is not a limitation. Is that so?

Comment: I only mentioned "force loading" for historical reasons. You really shouldn't need to worry about it. `sudo /sbin/modprobe ip_tables` would force load iptables and then `sudo /sbin/modprobe ip_conntrack` would force load the stateful connection tracking framework. Those examples are many years old, and syntax or names may have changes since